# AmCharts: Limit Y-Axs -Range and cut out non-periodical gaps

Tags: plot, linechart, amcharts

I have a problem with amCharts after trying a lot of settings.

I want to limit the range of the y-axis from 1-150 and do not want amCharts to plot data points with the value 0. There is no time-period in the x-range. I created a fiddle of my actual result: http://jsfiddle.net/zt9exqwq/5/

```js
var chartData = [{"position":"114","datum":"20.12.2014"},{"position":"0","datum":"24.12.2014"},{"position":"127","datum":"29.12.2014"},{"position":"128","datum":"02.01.2015"},{"position":"125","datum":"05.01.2015"},{"position":"132","datum":"09.01.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"13.01.2015"},{"position":"131","datum":"17.01.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"20.01.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"24.01.2015"},{"position":"88","datum":"28.01.2015"},{"position":"89","datum":"01.02.2015"},{"position":"94","datum":"04.02.2015"},{"position":"86","datum":"08.02.2015"},{"position":"80","datum":"12.02.2015"},{"position":"83","datum":"16.02.2015"},{"position":"82","datum":"19.02.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"23.02.2015"},{"position":"109","datum":"27.02.2015"},{"position":"100","datum":"03.03.2015"},{"position":"98","datum":"06.03.2015"},{"position":"92","datum":"10.03.2015"},{"position":"99","datum":"14.03.2015"},{"position":"97","datum":"18.03.2015"},{"position":"93","datum":"21.03.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"25.03.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"29.03.2015"},{"position":"108","datum":"02.04.2015"},{"position":"106","datum":"06.04.2015"},{"position":"109","datum":"10.04.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"14.04.2015"},{"position":"107","datum":"17.04.2015"},{"position":"114","datum":"21.04.2015"},{"position":"109","datum":"25.04.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"29.04.2015"},{"position":"111","datum":"02.05.2015"},{"position":"101","datum":"06.05.2015"},{"position":"84","datum":"10.05.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"14.05.2015"},{"position":"74","datum":"17.05.2015"},{"position":"71","datum":"21.05.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"25.05.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"29.05.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"01.06.2015"},{"position":"66","datum":"05.06.2015"},{"position":"73","datum":"09.06.2015"},{"position":"78","datum":"13.06.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"16.06.2015"},{"position":"65","datum":"20.06.2015"},{"position":"67","datum":"24.06.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"28.06.2015"},{"position":"74","datum":"02.07.2015"},{"position":"68","datum":"05.07.2015"},{"position":"67","datum":"09.07.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"13.07.2015"},{"position":"74","datum":"17.07.2015"},{"position":"73","datum":"21.07.2015"}];

    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "dataDateFormat": "DD.MM.YYYY",
    "balloon": {
        "borderThickness": 1,
        "shadowAlpha": 0
    },
    "graphs": [{
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.5,
        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "bulletSize": 8,
        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
        "valueField": "position",
        "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'><span style='font-size:13px;'>[[category]]</span><br>[[value]]</div>"
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "integersOnly": true,
        "maximum": 150,
        "minimum": 1,
        "reversed": true,
        "axisAlpha": 1,
        "dashLength": 2,
        "position": "left",
        "title": "Position"
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "cursorAlpha":0.2,
        "valueLineAlpha":0.2
    },
    "categoryField": "datum",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "dashLength": 1,
    },
    "dataProvider": chartData

});

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);

zoomChart();

function zoomChart() {
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width : 100%;
 height : 500px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

**Here's what it actual looks like:**
[image]

**And here's what I want to have:**
[image]

Has anybody an idea? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Value axis

To set the the scale for the value axis, we can use its [`minimum`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minimum) and [`maximum`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#maximum) properties. However, even if we set those two, the chart will try to round up value axis increments to "pretty" numbers, hence it will still display 0.

To work around that we will use another value axis property [`strictMinMax`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#strictMinMax). It will ensure that our value axis scale is crisply cut at 0 and 15 values.

However we now lose the first and last labels. We'll use [guides](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide) to add labels for 1 and 150 values.

Combined code for the above is this:

```
  "valueAxes": [{
    "integersOnly": true,
    "maximum": 150,
    "minimum": 1,
    "strictMinMax": true,
    "reversed": true,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "dashLength": 2,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Position",
    "guides": [{
      "value": 1,
      "label": "1"
    }, {
      "value": 150,
      "label": "150"
    }]
  }]
```

### Gaps

Zero is a valid number and a value. If you need to display a gap in place of the zero-value data points, you will need to set the value for those to `null`.

If you can't replace that directly in your data, you can add some custom code to iterate through the data and replace zero values with `null`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
  if (chartData[i].position == 0)
    chartData[i].position = null;
}
```

In order to display gaps, we will also need to set [`connect: false`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#connect) for the graph.

And since your data is at irregular date intervals, we'll also set [`gapPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#gapPeriod) to some larger period (say 10) so that gaps are not displayed whenever you have a distance bigger than 1 day between two adjacent data points.

Here's combined working chart:

```js
    var chartData = [{"position":"114","datum":"20.12.2014"},{"position":"0","datum":"24.12.2014"},{"position":"127","datum":"29.12.2014"},{"position":"128","datum":"02.01.2015"},{"position":"125","datum":"05.01.2015"},{"position":"132","datum":"09.01.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"13.01.2015"},{"position":"131","datum":"17.01.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"20.01.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"24.01.2015"},{"position":"88","datum":"28.01.2015"},{"position":"89","datum":"01.02.2015"},{"position":"94","datum":"04.02.2015"},{"position":"86","datum":"08.02.2015"},{"position":"80","datum":"12.02.2015"},{"position":"83","datum":"16.02.2015"},{"position":"82","datum":"19.02.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"23.02.2015"},{"position":"109","datum":"27.02.2015"},{"position":"100","datum":"03.03.2015"},{"position":"98","datum":"06.03.2015"},{"position":"92","datum":"10.03.2015"},{"position":"99","datum":"14.03.2015"},{"position":"97","datum":"18.03.2015"},{"position":"93","datum":"21.03.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"25.03.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"29.03.2015"},{"position":"108","datum":"02.04.2015"},{"position":"106","datum":"06.04.2015"},{"position":"109","datum":"10.04.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"14.04.2015"},{"position":"107","datum":"17.04.2015"},{"position":"114","datum":"21.04.2015"},{"position":"109","datum":"25.04.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"29.04.2015"},{"position":"111","datum":"02.05.2015"},{"position":"101","datum":"06.05.2015"},{"position":"84","datum":"10.05.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"14.05.2015"},{"position":"74","datum":"17.05.2015"},{"position":"71","datum":"21.05.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"25.05.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"29.05.2015"},{"position":"0","datum":"01.06.2015"},{"position":"66","datum":"05.06.2015"},{"position":"73","datum":"09.06.2015"},{"position":"78","datum":"13.06.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"16.06.2015"},{"position":"65","datum":"20.06.2015"},{"position":"67","datum":"24.06.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"28.06.2015"},{"position":"74","datum":"02.07.2015"},{"position":"68","datum":"05.07.2015"},{"position":"67","datum":"09.07.2015"},{"position":"72","datum":"13.07.2015"},{"position":"74","datum":"17.07.2015"},{"position":"73","datum":"21.07.2015"}];

for(var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
  if (chartData[i].position == 0)
    chartData[i].position = null;
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataDateFormat": "DD.MM.YYYY",
  "balloon": {
    "borderThickness": 1,
    "shadowAlpha": 0
  },
  "graphs": [{
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.5,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bulletSize": 8,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
    "valueField": "position",
    "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'><span style='font-size:13px;'>[[category]]</span><br>[[value]]</div>",
    "connect": false,
    "gapPeriod": 10
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "integersOnly": true,
    "maximum": 150,
    "minimum": 1,
    "strictMinMax": true,
    "reversed": true,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "dashLength": 2,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Position",
    "guides": [{
      "value": 1,
      "label": "1"
    }, {
      "value": 150,
      "label": "150"
    }]
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "cursorAlpha":0.2,
    "valueLineAlpha":0.2
  },
  "categoryField": "datum",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "dashLength": 1,
  },
  "dataProvider": chartData

});

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);

zoomChart();

function zoomChart() {
  chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
   width : 100%;
  height : 500px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```